# Count by a criteria across multiple files with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna use a simple code to solve this problem with Python and Pandas.

I have multiple files:

```
0001.HK_2020-04-16.CSV
0002.HK_2020-04-16.CSV
0003.HK_2020-04-16.CSV
...
0700.HK_2020-04-16.CSV
```

Each of the file contains the below data:

```
Date    Price_CHG
1/5/2015    -0.77
1/6/2015    -2.00
...
12/15/2015  0.12
12/16/2015  -0.88
```

And i wanna loop through all the files, and return 1 dataframe contains the below:

```
Date      | Count of Price_CHG > 0 | Count of Price_CHG < 0
1/5/2015
1/6/2015
...
12/15/2015
12/16/2015
```

What's the pimpliest way to do it with Python and Pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want a DataFrame for each csv or only one DataFrame?

Comment: Do you have a *specific* question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
csv_name_list = ['0001.HK_2020-04-16.CSV
0002.HK_2020-04-16.CSV'....]


df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csv) for csv in csv_name_list])
pd.crosstab(df['Date'],
             df['Price_CHG'].ge(0).map({True : 'Count of Price_CHG > 0',
                                        False : 'Count of Price_CHG < 0'}))
```

**or to get N DataFrame:**

```
def crosstab_from_csv(csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    return pd.crosstab(df['Date'],
             df['Price_CHG'].ge(0).map({True : 'Count of Price_CHG > 0',
                                        False : 'Count of Price_CHG < 0'}))

list(map(crosstab_from_csv, csv_name_list))
```

Comment: hi Ansev, sorry i should have make this clearer.."Count of Price_CHG > 0", "Count of Price_CHG < 0" should be the count, of Price_CHG >0 or <0.

Comment: we can filter  != 0 before: `m = df['Price_CHG'].ne(0)` and then `df.loc[m, 'Date']` and `df.loc[m, 'Price_CHG'].ge(0).map({True : 'Count of Price_CHG > 0',
                                        False : 'Count of Price_CHG < 0'}))`